# Drop rows with duplicates for a column, only for duplicates that appear on subsequent consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a `Date` column in datetime format as shown below.

When looking at consecutive days I would like to drop rows with repeated `Name` values, keeping the earliest date for each `Name`.

So for the following dataframe:

```
Date        Name  Points
2020-04-24  John  3
2020-04-25  John  5
2020-04-26  John  8
2020-04-24  Bob   0
2020-04-25  Bob   0
2020-07-20  John  2
2020-07-21  John  7
```

The desired result is:

```
Date        Name  Points
2020-04-24  John  3
2020-04-24  Bob   0
2020-07-20  John  2
```

Note that the data are not necessarily sorted as above. The data may be sorted by `Date` and then `Name` or some other order.

Comment: Are your dates always sorted as in your example?

Comment: I'm guessing that final row should be 2020-**07**-21?

Comment: @Erfan No, thanks for bringing this up. The sample data were sorted for simplicity. The actual data are sorted by date (and possibly by name after that).

Comment: @noah Yes! Just fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The following method works for ANY data order:**

Sort by name/date, apply a date shift and check for delta.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date':['2020-07-21', '2020-04-24', '2020-04-25', '2020-04-25', '2020-04-26', '2020-07-20', '2020-04-24'], 'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'Bob', 'John', 'John', 'Bob'], 'Points':[0,3,5,0,8,2,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.sort_values(['Name', 'Date'], inplace=True)
print(df[df['Date'].shift(1)-df['Date']!= '-1 days'])

#print(df) - Note not sorted
         Date  Name  Points
0  2020-07-21  John       7
1  2020-04-25  John       5
2  2020-04-24  John       3
3  2020-04-25   Bob       0
4  2020-04-26  John       8
5  2020-07-20  John       2
6  2020-04-24   Bob       0
#print(df) - Output
        Date  Name  Points
6 2020-04-24   Bob       0
2 2020-04-24  John       3
5 2020-07-20  John       2
```

**The following method works for ONLY the data order in the question:**

I'll leave this here in case someone in the future finds it helpful. After clarifications it is obsolete for this specific question.

Using shift to compare to previous name:

```
df=df[df['Name'].shift(1) != df['Name']]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date':['2020-04-24', '2020-04-25', '2020-04-26', '2020-04-24', '2020-04-25', '2020-04-20', '2020-04-21', ], 'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'John', 'John', ], 'Points':[3, 5, 8, 0, 0, 2, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df=df[df['Name'].shift(1) != df['Name']]
print(df)
```

Comment: This works because the dates and names are sorted, but what if they were not?

Comment: I assumed their data would be sorted given the way the question was posed. If the data isn't guaranteed to be sorted like in the question then it is a very different question

Comment: Fair enough, would be wise to put that as a note for OP and other users. +1 besides that.

Comment: I added an option for non sorted